# How to get focus on a single textbox except on some conditions?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to set the focus in a single textbox and some text must be entered in the textbox to move the focus out of it. But there is an exception that I should be able click on the buttons on the page without any entry in that textbox.

Here is what I have done using JavaScript...

```
          function Validate() {
              var field1 = document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID %>').value;

              if (field1 == "") {
                  alert("Please Enter some value");
                  document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID %>').focus();
                  return false;
              }
              else {
                  return true;
              }
          }
```

And I have called it like...

```
          onblur="return Validate();"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Script. (jquery required)

```
  $(function() {
        $('input[id=word]').blur(function() {
            var txtClone = $(this).val();
        if(txtClone=="")$(this).focus();
        });
    });
```

and here is a html tag

```
<input type='text' id='word'  name='word'>
```

As you've asked, focus won't move away unless you entered some text and able to click on button outside.

Comment: Whr have you called that JQuery?